# Adding vanilla javascript to wordpress; Please advise

Tags: javascript

I'm working through a tutorial test for wordpress development

I have this code:

```
function TopHeading(target) {
    $(target).style.fontsize = "20px";
}

TopHeading(".top-page-heading");
```

Is it addaction("Location" , "Function Name") all that I need to add?  tags too?

Total noob. Just looking for some direction.

Comment: could you please clarify your question? I don't understand if you need to convert your jQuery code to vanilla javascript, or if you need advice with wp's  `add_action()`.

Comment: My mistake. I had a couple questions mixed up. addaction() so that it will only affect those items with that class.